# Fulton and Harris -- Exercise 1.1

Tags: representation-theory

The exercise states that we should verify that if we define $\rho^*(g) = \rho(g^{-1})^T$ then this definition satisfies the relation

$$ \langle \rho^*(g)(v^*), \rho(g)(v) \rangle = \langle v^*, v \rangle $$

I don't really have any idea of how to start on this without resorting to facts about matrices, but my understanding is that in general representation theory we're only supposed to view representations as abstract linear transformations in the group of automorphisms of $V$, not as concrete matrices. Is that correct? If so, what sort of properties of representations should I be using to prove this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll asume that your notation is $$\langle \phi, v\rangle=\phi^Tv=\phi(v), $$ for $v\in V$ and $\phi\in V^*$.
So by the definitions $$\langle \rho^*(g)(v^*), \rho(g)(v) \rangle=\langle \rho(g^{-1})^T(v^*), \rho(g)(v) \rangle=\left(\rho(g^{-1})^T(v^*)\right)^T(\rho(g)(v))=v^{*T}\rho(g^{-1})\rho(g)(v)=v^{*T} v=v^*(v)=\langle v^*,v\rangle.$$

Comment: Just curious: what kind of matrix is $\rho(g)$ ? doesnt seem to be orthonormal but still something similar. Any idea ?

Comment: $\rho(g) $ is and endomorphism. To see it as a matrix first you need to fix a matrix in $V$. A priori you have no information about how the endomorphism is. What Do you mean by orthonormal basis?

Comment: Let $\rho(g)$ be an automorphism of a finite dimensional vector space $V$ (which "could" be the case here) and satisfy $\rho^*(g)  = \rho(g^{-1})^T$ then what kind of matrix is $\rho(g)$ is the question. Looks like matrix is not orthonormal but something similar. Orthonormal would imply $\rho(g)\rho(g)^T = Id$

Comment: $\rho$ does not satisfie $\rho^*(g) =\rho(g^{-1})^T$, its the definition of dual representation. And again, $\rho(g)$ is not a matrix, is an endomorphism. Endomorphism are linear functions that you van represent as matrix fixed a basis, but is not the same.

Comment: OK Thanks... just was wondering if $\rho^*(g)$ is the adjoint of $\rho(g)$ then $\rho^*(g) = \rho(g)^T \implies \rho(g^{-1})^T = \rho(g)^T \implies \rho(g^{-1}) = \rho(g) \implies \rho(g) = Id$. Yes you are right, we need to fix a basis.

Comment: @GuillermoGarcíaSáez This is perfect, thank you so much!